# D3 mysterious json parsing error

Tags: json, d3.js

D3 json parser is generating mysterious error. The json is as follows and the string is validated by an [online parser](http://jsonlint.com/) but d3 generates the error `"Unexpected token ]"`.

I'm totally confused. Please tell me whether it is the Json string's fault or the parser?

```
{
    "3090": [
        "59205",
        "72521"
    ],
    "3130": [
        "189939"
    ],
    "3150": [
        "58710"
    ],
    "3258": [
        "21738"
    ],
    "3717": [
        "61363"
    ],
    "3719": [
        "63965"
    ],
    "3989": [
        "47636",
        "47656",
        "58571",
        "58741",
        "58745",
        "59266",
        "139954"
    ],
    "3991": [
        "186438"
    ],
    "3992": [
        "38062",
        "41032"
    ],
    "4038": [
        "59198"
    ],
    "5009": [
        "189476"
    ],
    "027936": [
        "179047"
    ],
    "P391": [
        "13461",
        "679516",
        "978543"
    ],
    "M492": [
        "170321",
        "199900",
        "273415",
        "348748",
        "966475"
    ],
    "1P04": [
        "49027",
        "173470",
        "1029583"
    ],
    "N624": [
        "178491",
        "182573",
        "204070",
        "213200",
        "220640",
        "689284"
    ],
    "M187": [
        "65486",
        "162474",
        "167984",
        "210661",
        "218076",
        "224395",
        "256049",
        "295905",
        "298012",
        "301037",
        "307361",
        "318149",
        "320015",
        "327478",
        "329620",
        "334297",
        "334557",
        "634880",
        "714124",
        "788333",
        "976785",
        "1016630",
        "1017012",
        "1026645",
        "1048217",
        "1048218"
    ],
    "N622": [
        "51453",
        "150260",
        "230713",
        "632383",
        "806624"
    ],
    "N626": [
        "268476",
        "268481",
        "721098",
        "817611",
        "941123",
        "943528",
        "1033581"
    ],
    "057139": [
        "114172"
    ],
    "1F75": [
        "18520",
        "60105",
        "215892",
        "231772",
        "807606",
        "918089",
        "943877",
        "1039530"
    ],
    "V056": [
        "199919",
        "292498",
        "333106"
    ],
    "V275": [
        "24796",
        "28969",
        "29209",
        "40253",
        "303970",
        "326940",
        "332927",
        "334300",
        "597799",
        "780261"
    ],
    "K293": [
        "6956",
        "178352"
    ],
    "W415": [
        "22526"
    ]
}





    d3.json("data/ms_org_user.json", function(errUser, users){
        console.log(errUser);
        console.log(users);
    }
```

Comment: Change the object to array, and add an inner object?

Comment: I need fast access by key value so I prefer object. BTW, why do you suggest that? @iMom0

Comment: You have two json files, but the question shows only one. Are you sure the problem is not on the other file?

Comment: Yes. I tried with only one file. Let me edit the question. @PauloScardine

Comment: There must be something wrong with the file. The JSON you pasted here works fine for me with d3.json.  Can you link to the file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for Paul's thoughts.

Also, you can just use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to test out the strings.

```
JSON.parse('{"3090": ["59205", "72521"], ... "W415": ["22526"]}')
```